# Renaming specific path on resource route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have set this resource route in my Routes.rb

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :posts
  end
```

How can I rename the route name and path name specifically for `index`, which at the moment is

```
# route
 admin_posts GET    /admin/posts(.:format)            admin/posts#index

# path
admin_posts_path
```

rename to

`dashboard_path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your namespace definition in the routes.rb file, you can create a new "entry" for such controller and action, like:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :posts
end
get 'dashboard', to: 'admin/posts#index', as: :dashboard
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
resources :posts, except: [:index]
get 'your_url', to: 'controller@action', as: 'dashboard_path'
```

There is no support for renaming inside resources.

Comment: I've seen this solution, however I was wondering whether there's a more elegant way of doing it

Comment: Unfortunatelly no. You can add new actions inside the resource, but you can`t specify 'as' parameter for them. Like this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)